# Set www location in shiny::shinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, filepath, package-development

I am currently creating a shiny app that gets invoked with `shiny::shinyApp` via a wrapper function.

```
startApp <- function(param1, param2, ...){
  # in fact, ui and server change based on the parameters
  ui <- fluidPage()
  server <- function(...){}
  runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
}
```

When I include resources (like images, videos etc.), I currently use the `addResourcePath` command and include the resources with a prefix. However, I would like to add a "default resource path" (`appDir/www` in usual apps). There seems to be no suitable parameter in `shinyApp` or `runApp`. Setting the working directory to the resource folder or one level above does not work either.

Here is a short MWE.

```
## ~/myApp/app.R
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(tags$img(src = "image.gif")),
  server <- function(...){}
)

## ~/myApp/www/image.gif
# binary file
```

If I run the app via `RunApp("~/myApp")` everything works, but

```
setwd("~/myApp")
myApp <- shinyApp(source("app.R")$value)
runApp(myApp)
```

will fail to display the image. Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Context

The reason I want to start the app based on an `shiny.appobj` (an object that represents the app) rather than a file path is, that the latter approach does not work well with passing parameters to an app. [Here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/440) is a discussion about this topic.

The recommended way of passing parameters to an app that gets invoked by `runApp("some/path")` is as follows:

```
startApp <- function(param1, param2, ...) {
  .GlobalEnv$.param1 <- param1
  .GlobalEnv$.param2 <- param2
  .GlobalEnv$.ellipsis <- as.list(...)
  on.exit(rm(.param1, .param2, .ellipsis, envir = .GlobalEnv))
  runApp("~/myApp")
}
```

This approach is just ugly IMO and I get warnings when I build the package that contains the app together with the `startApp` function. Those warnings occur because the package then breaks the recommended scoping model for package development.

Answer (score -1):

In the help documentation in `shiny::runApp`, it says `appDir` could be either of the below:

> A directory containing server.R, plus, either ui.R or a www directory
>   that contains the file index.html.
>
> A directory containing app.R.
>
> An .R file containing a Shiny application, ending with an expression
>   that produces a Shiny app object.
>
> A list with ui and server components.
>
> A Shiny app object created by shinyApp.

When you run via `RunApp("~/myApp")`, it is **a directory containing app.R**
If you want to run via **a shiny app object created by shinyApp**

you can try things like

```
myapp_obj <- shinyApp(
  fluidPage(tags$img(src = "image.gif")),
  server <- function(...){}
)
runApp(myapp_obj)
```

**Update**
create a script *myapp_script.R* with

```
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(tags$img(src='image.gif')),
  server <- function(...){}
)
```

and then call `runApp("myapp_script.R")`

Comment: I am aware of that. The image will only be displayed when I start the app based on a directory path, but not when I start it from a `shiny.appobj` (using `print` or `runApp`).

Comment: how about creating a R script *myapp_script.R* with `shinyApp(
  fluidPage(tags$img(src = "image.gif")),
  server <- function(...){}
)`, and then call `runApp("myapp_script.R")`

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I actually want to to run `runApp` via an object that represents the app. I just updated the question to explain why this is the case.